# retry to load two scripts in componentdidmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to load two js scripts in componentdidmount and want a retry logic 4 times.

What would be the best way to handle two scripts in one function?

```
    function loadScript(scriptUrl1, scriptUrl2, retries = 4) {
        const getScript= document.createElement("script");

        getScript.onerror = () => {
            if (retries > 0) {
                loadScript(scriptUrl1, scriptUrl2, retries - 1);
            } else {
                console.log("failed to load")
            }
        }
        script1.src = scriptUrl1;
        script2.src = scriptUrl2;
    }
```

Comment: What would be the best way to handle two scripts in one function? edited question

Answer (score 0):

A second function would work here. For example with a while loop:

```
function loadScript(scriptUrl1, scriptUrl2, retries = 4) {
  function loadScriptLoop(url) {
    while (retries > 0) {
      const getScript = document.createElement("script")
      getScript.onerror = () => {
        if (retries > 0) {
          retries--
          continue
        } else {
          console.log("failed to load")
          break
        }
      }
      getScript.src = url
    }
  }

  ;[scriptUrl1, scriptUrl2].forEach(loadScriptLoop)
}
```

Though you could do the same thing with other types of loops.